# Is there a reliable PHP one liner to suffix/prefix array values?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I need to suffix array values which will in fact be a tag CSS, so I need to suffix one array with `:hover` and another with `:focus`

```
$elements = array('.one','.two','.three');
```

desired new arrays

```
$helements = array('.one:hover','.two:hover','.three:hover');
$felements = array('.one:focus','.two:focus','.three:focus');
```

I know I can do it with a loop but question is, is there a fast one liner for this?

Comment: Always the same value for every element of the array?

Comment: @Napolux, yes , it will be either :hover, or :focus suffix

Comment: You can probably use `array_map` or even `array_walk` for this.

Comment: Why are you looking for a "fast oneliner"? Do you think it'll work any better or faster than a plain old loop?

Comment: @CodeCaster , good question , is array_map, array_walk going to be faster than the loop?

Comment: The real question is: are you going to notice it? If you really want to know, benchmark it. Otherwise, go for the most readable code. Chances are that a few string operations are going to have an immeasurably small impact on your entire code.

Comment: @CodeCaster, is much more that 3 , that was just an example. Working on CSS generator and it can be well over 100 elements which is not much but for a loop search /replace it might be.

Comment: You can use regex. like [Regex to Add a postfix to each item of a PHP array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691789/regex-to-add-a-postfix-to-each-item-of-a-php-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$newelements = array_map(function($x){ return $x . ':hover'; }, $elements);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can alter the array itself (like my solution) or create a new array like [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37442699/208623). Your choice. ;)

You can just pass the `$item` as reference in order to change the original array directly.

```
$array = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
array_walk($array,function(&$item) {$item .= ':hover';});
```

The result is:

```
var_dump($array);

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "test1:hover"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "test2:hover"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "test3:hover"
}
```