# Regex to Add a postfix to each item of a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a PHP array of strings, which I would like to postfix with a character. below regular expression to add something prefix of each array elements:

```
$prefixed_array = preg_filter('/^/', 'prefix_', $array);
```

But, I need add postfix.

Essentially I would like to go from this:

```
$array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f"];
```

To this:

```
$array = ["a_M", "b_M", "c_M", "d_M", "f_M"];
```

I can do it with `foreach`, but need a regular expresion (Just Regex).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Arrays - Adding a String to all Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535846/php-arrays-adding-a-string-to-all-values)

Comment: @SahilGulati: Actually, this OP regex solution is taken from that very post. I think OP is interested in the regex way of adding suffixes to the PHP array which is more appropriate if there are additional pattern requirements (not sure if OP revealed all the details of the real-life problem).

Comment: @SahilGulati: I need just Regex. Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `preg_filter` with a regex for this, replace `^` with `$` (the end of string) (or `\z` - the very end of the string):

```
$array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f"];
$suffixed_array = preg_filter('/$/', '_M', $array);
print_r($suffixed_array);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/bhGlqi)

A non-regex way is to use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like this:

```
$suffixed_array = array_map(function ($s) {return $s . '_M';}, $array);
```

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/zUI81F).

Comment: I need to add prefix at start and end of value as well, then how this can be done via `preg_filter`?

Comment: @Hassaan I think you want to use `preg_replace` for this. Like `$arr = preg_replace('/^.*$/', 'PREF_$0_SUFF', $arr);`. Or `$arr = array_map(function ($s) {return 'prefix_' . $s . '_suffix';}, $arr)`

Answer (score 0):

additional approach using [array_map](http://php.net/array_map)

```
$array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f"];

$array = array_map(function($k) {
    return $k . '_M';
}, $array);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: This is actually part of my answer. Moreover, I think OP is interested in the *regex* way of solving the issue, otherwise, the [PHP Arrays - Adding a String to all Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535846/php-arrays-adding-a-string-to-all-values) post is enough.

Comment: I've saw your update after posting my answer , sorry